# How to upgrade aspnetcore.dll present in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I tried to upgrade aspnetcore.dll present in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv to latest version but after installing all the software from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download, aspnetcore.dll version is not changing.

I tried all installer from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Which installer will upgrade the version

Comment: I have nothing in my C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv. You can have a look at C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App ,there you may find the version of  aspnetcore.dll  that you want.

Comment: Hi Quing Guo , thanks for your kind reply but in my case the dll is present in System32\inetsrv folder